# Ho do i solve 403 Forbidden Error in zend framwork?

Tags: zend-framework, http-status-code-403, http-error

i have developed my website using zend framwork

when i have visit my website my website i have getting 403 Forbidden error on my home page

i have not getting this error on any other pages just getting error on home page

i don't have index.php file on my root directory but i have index.php file on my public folder on live server

i have write .htacess file to point my public folder on root directory

please can you let me know how to solve this error bucause i done R & D and there is some solution some are saying that it because you don't have index.php on root directory

but when i have put index file then my website not working

please help me to solve this problem

Following is My .htacess code on root director

```
# BEGIN SSL
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !^/public/
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ /public/$1

## EXPIRES CACHING ##
<IfModule mod_expires.c>
RewriteEngine on
RewriteCond %{HTTP_USER_AGENT} libwww-perl.* 
RewriteRule .* ? [F,L]
ExpiresActive On 
ExpiresByType image/jpg "access 1 month" 
ExpiresByType image/jpeg "access 1 month" 
ExpiresByType image/gif "access 1 year" 
ExpiresByType image/png "access 1 year" 
ExpiresByType text/css "access 1 month" 
ExpiresByType text/html "access 1 month" 
ExpiresByType application/pdf "access 1 month" 
ExpiresByType text/x-javascript "access 1 month" 
ExpiresByType application/x-shockwave-flash "access 1 month" 
ExpiresByType image/x-icon "access 1 year" 
ExpiresDefault "access 1 month"
</IfModule>
## EXPIRES CACHING ##
```

Answer (score 0):

Your RewriteRule should target to index.php

for example

`RewriteRule ^(.*)$ /public/index.php`

or your Virtual Host should have

```
<Directory />
    AllowOverride none
    Require all granted
</Directory>
```

EDIT:
Of course before you should exclude resources, finally your htaccess should like that:

```
RewriteEngine On

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !\.(?:css|js|jpe?g|gif|png)$ [NC]
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ /public/index.php [L]

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !^/public/
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ /public/$1
```

Comment: Hello sorry but when i do this changes my website give me lots of error like css , images are not loaded

Comment: # BEGIN SSL
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !^/public/
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ /public/index.php

Comment: Of course, because before you should exclude resources like that:
`RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} 
!\.(?:css|js|jpe?g|gif|png)$ [NC]
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ /public/index.php [L]`

Answer (score 0):

I have Tried Following solution and its work

Create an index.php in the root folder:

```
<?php 
define('RUNNING_FROM_ROOT', true);
include 'public/index.php';
```

Create a .htaccess file in the root folder:

```
SetEnv APPLICATION_ENV production

RewriteEngine On
RewriteRule .* index.php
```

Maybe set the APPLICATION_ENV to development whilst testing :)

Be aware that when referencing static files the baseUrl() view helper now points to your root folder not your public/ folder.